# Multiple Rewrite Rules for .htaccess, Redirect to www while including index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

Specifically, I want to redirect all non-www pages to www, while also running an index.php file located in my root directory. To solve both of these problems I am using `.htaccess`.

I have already set up my site to run the PHP file to run in every directory. But the moment I add redirection from non-www to www it breaks.

The problem seems to be, that the multiple rewrite rules conflict with each other. Either one runs and the other does not, or the site just responds with a 500 error.

My question is, should multiple Rewrite rules be "combined" into one? Or am I just using those multiple rules wrong? (Or is it just some strange syntax thing I messed up? I have been working on this for a while haha)

Any help is very much appreciated.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php  [L,QSA]
# Redirect to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What happens if you swap the order of the two, so that the domain redirect comes before the file?

Comment: "I have already set up my site to run the PHP file to run in every directory." - And what does that rule look like? That's not what the rule you've posted does?

Comment: @MrWhite, the ```RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d``` redirects to index always. None of those files actually exist. 

Comment: @ChrisHaas Unfortunately that did not work, thank you though.

Comment: The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` condition simply asserts that the request does not map to a directory on the filesystem. "run the PHP file to run in every directory" - The directive you posted sends all requests to `index.php` in the document root, not "in every directory".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found this works:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] #if not already index.php
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #only if NOT a FILE (directory / non-existent file)
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L] #redirect to index.php
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
> RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [R=301,L] #redirect to https://www
> </IfModule>
> ```

This cannot possibly "work" as written, as there are a number of errors:

- You are missing the opening `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` directive. However, this `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required anyway and should be removed.
- Line-end comments are not supported by Apache. Specifically, the following line will result in a 500 error due to "bad flag delimiters":

  ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #only if NOT a FILE (directory / non-existent file)
  ```

  (**UPDATE:** If you are not seeing a 500 error response here, it's possible you are on a LiteSpeed server; not Apache? On LiteSpeed, this line-end comment appears to work as intended!)
- Your external redirect (at the end) that redirects to `www` never gets processed for anything other than requests for directories (including the root) or real files (except `index.php`). This redirect needs to go first, *before* the existing rewrites. However, *see the next point...*
- You are incorrectly using `REQUEST_FILENAME` (the absolute filesystem path) in the target URL - this will result in a *malformed* redirect. You could use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead (full URL-path), but note that you also have a double slash issue. So, it would need to be rewritten like the following instead:

  ```
   RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
  ```

Minor points:

- The `RewriteBase` is not being used here and could be safely removed. (Unless you have other directives that use this?)

### Summary

Bringing the above points together we have:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to https://www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Stop here if already index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Only if NOT a FILE (non-existent file)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Rewrite to index.php (in the document root)
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Note that this still rewrites directories to `/index.php`, contrary to what your *comment* stated.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: I see I have made quite a few mistakes. I'm as confused as you were as to why my site did not return a 500 error when I used that old code . Regarding the <ifmodule>, you can see in my code I had the closing tag, this was an accident when copy/pasting the relevant parts of the file. I do have the opening one, I just didn't paste it in my answer. Thank you for your help. I really have learned a lot.

Comment: "why my site did not return a 500 error" - Maybe you are on a LiteSpeed server and not Apache? LiteSpeed is a "drop-in replacement for Apache", however, there are some significant differences. For one, that line-end comment on the `RewriteCond` directive does actually appear to work "as intended" on LiteSpeed!

Answer (score 0):

After lots of tinkering/research, I found this works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] #if not already index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #only if NOT a FILE (directory / non-existent file)
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] #redirect to index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [R=301,L] #redirect to https://www
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: There are a number of _critical_ errors here, which I've addressed [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63358539/369434).